# First row of the `Gridview` always gets deleted instead of the user selected for deletion

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to remove a selected user from my `GridView` but when I select the delete buttone next to the user it then deletes the first row of the Gridview instead of the user selected.

This is my `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView
                            ID="gvUsers"
                            runat="server"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            Width="100%"
                            GridLines="None"
                            CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnPagesize" runat="server" />
                                        <img id="imgPreview" class="img-rounded" style="width: 38px; height: 38px; margin-top: -10px; margin-bottom: -12px" alt="" src="" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle Width="4%" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <label id="lblFullName" style="font-weight: normal;"></label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="cssSearch" Width="28%" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <label id="lblEmail" style="font-weight: normal;"></label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="cssSearch" Width="24%" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dob">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <label id="lblDob" style="font-weight: normal;"></label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle Width="12%" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-Width="7%">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnStatus" runat="server" />
                                        <label id="lblStatus" style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal;"></label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <label id="lblRole" style="font-weight: normal;"></label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle Width="8%" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Account" ItemStyle-Width="7%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <label id="lblAccountStatus" style="font-weight: normal; font-size: large;"></label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-Width="8%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <a id="aEditUserDetails" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                            <i class="ti-pencil-alt" style="font-size: large"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <a id="aDeleteUser" style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-danger" style="font-size: medium"></i>
                                        </a>

                                        <!-- BEGIN Modal Confirm -->
                                        <div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                                        <h4>Are you sure?</h4>
                                                        <br />
                                                        <a id="aDeleteUserModal" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</a>
                                                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" value="No" />                                                            
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- END Modal Confirm -->
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

Then my code as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var selectedPageSize = 10   /* Default size is 10. */
        var currentPageIndex = 1    /* Default pageindex is 1. */

        $(function () {
            /* Retrieve list of users when page loads. */
            GetUsers(currentPageIndex, selectedPageSize);
        });

        $(document).on("keyup", "[id*=txtSearch]", function () {
            /* Retrieve list of users when any key is pressed in search box (txtSearch). */
            GetUsers(currentPageIndex, selectedPageSize);
        });

        $(document).on("click", ".Pager .page", function () {
            currentPageIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('page'))
            GetUsers(currentPageIndex, selectedPageSize);
        });

        function changePagesize(obj) {
            selectedPageSize = $("[id*=ddlPageSize]").val();
            GetUsers(currentPageIndex, selectedPageSize);
        }

        function SearchKey() {
            return jQuery.trim($("[id*=txtSearch]").val());
        };
        function GetUsers(pageIndex, pageSize) {
            /* Pass parameters in array, gData.*/
            var gData = [];
            gData[0] = pageIndex;
            gData[1] = pageSize;
            gData[2] = SearchKey();
            var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ gData: gData });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "users.aspx/GetUsers",
                data: jsonData,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: "true",
                success: BindUsersList,
                failure: function (response) {
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
        var row;
        function BindUsersList(response) {
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
            var xml = $(xmlDoc);
            var users = xml.find("dsUsers");
            var html = '<table id="gvUsers">';
            if (row == null) {
                row = $("#<%=gvUsers.ClientID %> tr:last-child").clone(true);
            }
            $("#<%=gvUsers.ClientID %> tr").not($("#<%=gvUsers.ClientID %> tr:first-child")).remove();
            html += $("#<%=gvUsers.ClientID %>").html();
            if (users.length > 0) {
                $.each(users, function () {
                    html += "<tr>";

                    $(row).find("[id*=imgPreview]").attr("src", "../imageHandler.ashx?user_id_pk=" + $(this).find("user_id_pk").text() + "");
                    $(row).find("[id*=lblFullName]").html($(this).find("FullName").text());
                    $(row).find("[id*=lblEmail]").html($(this).find("email").text());
                    $(row).find("[id*=lblDob]").html($(this).find("dob").text());

                    if ($(this).find("user_status").text() == "true") {
                        $(row).find("[id*=lblStatus]").html("Active");
                        $(row).find("[id*=lblStatus]").attr("class", "label label-success label-transparent");
                    }
                    else {
                        $(row).find("[id*=lblStatus]").html("Inactive");
                        $(row).find("[id*=lblStatus]").attr("class", "label label-danger label-transparent");
                    }
                    if ($(this).find("accountStatus").text() == "locked") {
                        $(row).find("[id*=lblAccountStatus]").attr("class", "ti-lock text-danger");
                        $(row).find("[id*=lblAccountStatus]").attr("data-toggle", "tooltip");
                        $(row).find("[id*=lblAccountStatus]").attr("data-placement", "left");
                        $(row).find("[id*=lblAccountStatus]").attr("title", "Account locked due to invalid login attempts.");
                    }
                    else {
                        $(row).find("[id*=lblAccountStatus]").attr("class", "ti-unlock text-success");
                    }

                    $(row).find("[id*=lblRole]").html($(this).find("user_role").text());

                    $(row).find("[id*=aEditUserDetails]").attr("data-user-id", $(this).find("user_id_pk").text());
                    $(row).find("[id*=aEditUserDetails]").attr("title", "Edit User Details");

                    $(row).find("[id*=aDeleteUserModal]").attr("data-user-id", $(this).find("user_id_pk").text());

                    $("#<%=gvUsers.ClientID %>").append(row);
                    row = $("#<%=gvUsers.ClientID %> tr:last-child").clone(true);

                    html += $(row).html();
                    html += "</tr>";
                });
                var pager = xml.find("dtPager");
                $("[id*=divPager]").gvPager({
                    ActiveCssClass: "current",
                    PagerCssClass: "pager",
                    PageIndex: parseInt(pager.find("PageIndex").text()),
                    PageSize: parseInt(pager.find("PageSize").text()),
                    RecordCount: parseInt(pager.find("RecordCount").text())
                });
                $(".cssSearch").each(function () {
                    var searchPattern = new RegExp('(' + SearchKey() + ')', 'ig');
                    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(searchPattern, "<span class = 'highlight'>" + SearchKey() + "</span>"));
                });
            } else {
                var empty_row = row.clone(true);
                $("td:first-child", empty_row).attr("colspan", $("td", row).length);
                $("td:first-child", empty_row).attr("align", "center");
                $("td:first-child", empty_row).html("No Data Available.");
                $("td", empty_row).not($("td:first-child", empty_row)).remove();
                $("#<%=gvUsers.ClientID %>").append(empty_row);
            }
            html += '</table>';
        };

        /* Edit user details. */
        $("[id*=aEditUser]").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "users.aspx/EditUser",
                data: '{userId: ' + $(this).data('user-id') + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json",
                async: "true",
                success: function (response) {
                    location.href = "newuser.aspx?uid=" + response.d;
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    Notification(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText, 'Error', 'error');
                }
            });
        });

        /* Delete user. */
        $("[id*=aDeleteUserModal]").click(function () {
            //var ans = confirm("Are you sure?");
            //if (ans == true) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "users.aspx/DeleteUser",
                    data: '{userId: ' + $(this).data('user-id') + '}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    datatype: "json",
                    async: "true",
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.d == 'DeletePermissionDenied') {
                            Notification('This feature is disabled in demo version.', 'Permission Denied', 'error');
                            //Notification('You dont have the permission to delete the data, contact your administrator.', 'Permission Denied', 'error');
                        }
                        else if (response.d == 'Success') {
                            GetUsers(currentPageIndex, selectedPageSize);
                            Notification('User deleted successfully.', 'Success', 'success');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        Notification(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText, 'Error', 'error');
                    }
                });
            //}
        });
    </script>
```

And the the code behind:

```
private void BindUsersRow()
{
    DataTable dtUsers = new DataTable();
    dtUsers.Columns.Add("user_id_pk");
    dtUsers.Columns.Add("FullName");
    dtUsers.Columns.Add("email");
    dtUsers.Columns.Add("dob");
    dtUsers.Columns.Add("accountStatus");
    dtUsers.Columns.Add("user_role");
    dtUsers.Columns.Add("user_status");        
    dtUsers.Rows.Add();
    gvUsers.DataSource = dtUsers;
    gvUsers.DataBind();
    //gvUsers.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
    //gvUsers.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
}

[WebMethod]
public static string GetUsers(List<string> gData)
{
    string query = "sp_um_getUsersList";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchKey", gData[2]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageIndex", gData[0]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageSize", gData[1]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userStatus", strUserStatus);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecordCount", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    return GetData(cmd, int.Parse(gData[0]), int.Parse(gData[1])).GetXml();
}

private static DataSet GetData(SqlCommand cmd, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONN"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                sda.Fill(ds, "dsUsers");
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("dtPager");
                dt.Columns.Add("PageIndex");
                dt.Columns.Add("PageSize");
                dt.Columns.Add("RecordCount");
                dt.Rows.Add();
                dt.Rows[0]["PageIndex"] = pageIndex;
                dt.Rows[0]["PageSize"] = pageSize;
                dt.Rows[0]["RecordCount"] = cmd.Parameters["@RecordCount"].Value;
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                return ds;
            }
        }
    }
}

[WebMethod]
public static string EditUser(int userId)
{
    string str = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(DataControl.Encrypt(userId.ToString()));
    return str;
}

[WebMethod]
public static string DeleteUser(int userId)
{
    string result = "";
    if (isDeletePermission.Equals(false))
    {
        result = "DeletePermissionDenied";
    }
    else
    {
        string strQuery = "EXEC sp_um_deleteUser " + userId + "," + int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"].ToString()) + "";
        bool isResult = DataControl.ExecuteNonQuery(strQuery);
        if (isResult.Equals(true))
        {
            result = "Success";
        }
        else
        {
            result = "Error";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

However when I select to edit the user it works, I can edit and update with now problems.  Its only when I try to delete the user that this happens where it deletes the first row irrespective of the user  (row) selected for deletion.

Thanks,

Please note that this question has been asked earlier by myself but realized that I didn't give enough code and explanation so I thought I will rather post a new question with more details.

Comment: Your issues is somewhere on the javascript part of this code, probably not select the correct user id.. When you search for the 'user_id_pk' you probably select something else...

Comment: I think so as well, but went over and over it but can't find where the problem is.

Comment: Check this line `$(row).find("[id*=aDeleteUserModal]").attr("data-user-id", $(this).find("user_id_pk").text());`  if the `find` finds the correct id

Comment: Check here : `row = $("#<%=gvUsers.ClientID %> tr:last-child").clone(true);` if the clone keeps the correct ids...

Comment: and check here and here if they find the correct ids `$("[id*=aDeleteUserModal]").click(function () {`     
`data: '{userId: ' + $(this).data('user-id') + '}',` all of them are javascript and you need to check them with the browser when you run it

Comment: It keeps bringing up user ID of 1?  So its not getting the selected user ID.  But this is only for the delete, the edit one works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the cloning of the line always, but there will be repeated lines in the Dom of page.
It should be left like this:

```
var row;
function BindUsersList(response) {
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
    var xml = $(xmlDoc);
    var users = xml.find("dsUsers");
    var html = '<table id="gvUsers">';

    row = $("#<%=gvUsers.ClientID %> tr:last-child").clone(true);

    [...]
```

Another possible error, would be to collect the ID, I would modify it, so that the AJAX function is not confused with the click.

```
/* Edit user details. */
        $("[id*=aEditUser]").click(function () {
           var idUser =  $(this).data('user-id');                 

           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "users.aspx/EditUser",
                data: '{userId: ' + idUser + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json",
                async: "true",
                success: function (response) {
                    location.href = "newuser.aspx?uid=" + response.d;
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    Notification(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText, 'Error', 'error');
                }
            });
        });
```